# Android: MySQL and JSON so close?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I got it all setup and I'm having the same problem as many users I've read about, where the url is only displayed on the app screen. My LogCat reads:

Error in http connection java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

My permissions are set as suggested in the Manifest. I have the app set to connect to a webserver running the php script that seems to output correctly when navigated to. I am running this in an emulator and using Eclipse Helios 1.3.2 Service Release 2. All advice would be helpful.

JSONTester.java:

```
package com.uDrew.JSONTester;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class JSONTester extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources  
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.  
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
    rootLayout.addView(txt);  
    setContentView(rootLayout);  

    // Set the text and call the connect function.  
    txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
  //call the method to run the data retrieval
    txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121)); 



}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://www.myrealdomain.com/city.php"; 



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1970"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                            ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                            ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                    );
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString; 
}    

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.uDrew.JSONTester"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".JSONTester"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

city.php:

```
<?php

      mysql_connect("www.myrealdomain.com:3306","root","mypassword");

      mysql_select_db("deal");

      $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");

      while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

              $output[]=$e;

           print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

This PHP file outputs the following when simply being navigated to: `[{"id":"1","name":"Andrew","sex":"1","birthyear":"1987"}]`

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: year in C:\Inetpub\city.php on line 7
```

This leads me to believe there is nothing wrong with my PHP besides not being passed the variable from the Android app because I'm merely navigating to it on a browser.

Please let me know what this may be.

Comment: Btw, to "convert response to string" you can use EntityUtils.toString(entity). Bloody *Utils keeps popping up on me every time I implement the same functionality myself. Don't repeat same mistakes (-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either fix the PHP error or type

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Your JSON response needs to be clean
But the permission error should be another problem.

Can you give us more LogCat details?

Comment: Wouldn't the JSON respond with an error if it had no value .$_REQUEST['year'] passed to it from the Android application?

Comment: Ran the application today to get you more information regarding LogCat details and I it ran perfectly. I have not changed one bit since the original posted source. Odd. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I faced the same problem. I got this error "Error in http connection java.net.SocketException: Permission denied" when I was trying to run a client on phone. The problem was, I had my WiFi turned off. May be it was same in your case.